# Is that one request only can push notification to one device in the new APNS provider API?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I saw the the APNS documentation write that the path must be `:path    /3/device/<device-token>`, the `path` header should with one device token, generally notification will be sent to so many devices, should I send them one by one? Have better way to solve it?